# Set custom line heights for each font-family with tailwind CSS

Tags: tailwind-css

I am using two different font families in my tailwind app. One Serif and one Sans Serif. Defined like this in my `tailwind.config.js`:

```
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ['mr-eaves-modern', 'sans-serif'],
        serif: ['kepler-std-semicondensed', 'serif']
      }
    },
```

I would like to change the `lineHeight` for each size of my Serif font and Sans Serif font independently. So far, the only option that works is to set `leading-tight` to each and every `text-2xl` which becomes very repetitive.

Is there a way to set default fontSize and lineHeight for various text size/family combinations?

Answer (score 0):

you can customize it with tailwind, like this

```js
extend: {
  fontFamily: {
    sans: ['mr-eaves-modern', 'sans-serif'],
    serif: ['kepler-std-semicondensed', 'serif'],
  },
  lineHeight: {
    'sans-xs': '1',
    'sans-sm': '1.25',
    'sans-base': '1.5',
    'serif-xs': '1',
    'serif-sm': '1.25',
    'serif-base': '1.5',
  },
},
```

then you can use like

```html
<div class="font-sans text-sans-xs">Lorem ipsum.</div>
<div class="font-serif text-serif-xs">Lorem ipsum.</div>
```

I am very sorry to say that as far as I know, it does not seem very easy to do it with a single class.